# Check for an element in the rest of the list (lx)

Tags: haskell

i recently picked up Haskell and i am having trouble putting in code the way to look if an element is in the rest of the list `(x:lx)` in this case in `lx`.
My code:

```
atmostonce:: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
atmostonce [] y = True
atmostonce (x:lx) y 
 | (x==y) && (`lx` == y) = False
 | otherwise = True
```

The way it is now checks for the first element `(x==y)` but i don't know how to check if the element `y` exists in `lx`. The thing i am actually trying to accomplish is to find out if in the list of Intigers `lx` the number `y` contains 0 or 1 times and return `True` otherwise return `False`

Comment: Don't comment when your post doesn't look the way you wanted, _edit_ it. As chi showed, you can have code-block markup by indenting four spaces on the left.

Comment: OK sorry i am new to stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [**`elem`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:elem) function:

```
atmostonce:: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
atmostonce [] y = True
atmostonce (x:lx) y | x /= y = atmostonce lx y
                    | otherwise = not $ elem y lx
```

You better first check if the element `x` is **not** equal to `y`. If that is the case, you simply call the recursive part `atmostonce lx y`: you thus search further in the list.

In case `x == y`, (the `otherwise` case), you need to check if there is another element in `lx` (the remainder of the list), that is equal to `x`. If that is the case, you need to return `False`, because in that case there are multiple instances in the list. Otherwise you return `True`.

Furthermore you can generalize your function further:

```
atmostonce:: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Bool
atmostonce [] y = True
atmostonce (x:lx) y | x /= y = atmostonce lx y
                    | otherwise = not $ elem y lx
```

[**`Eq`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Eq) is a typeclass, it means that there are functions `==` and `/=` defined on `a`. So you can call them, regardless of the real type of `a` (`Int`, `String`, whatever).

Finally in the first case, you can use an underscore (`_`) which means you *don't care* about the value (although in this case it doesn't matter). You can perhaps change the order of the cases, since they are disjunct, and this makes the function syntactically *total*:

```
atmostonce:: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Bool
atmostonce (x:lx) y | x /= y = atmostonce lx y
                    | otherwise = not $ elem y lx
atmostonce _ _ = True
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several implementations you could use for this, one that I see which avoids applying `length` to a potentially infinite list is

```
atmostonce xs y
    = (<= 1)
    $ length
    $ take 2
    $ filter (== y) xs
```

This removes all elements from `xs` that are not equal to `y`, then takes at most 2 of those (`take 2 [1] == [1]`, `take 2 [] == []`), calculates the length (it's safe to use here because we know `take 2` won't return an infinite list), then checks if that is no more than 1.  Alternatively you could solve this using direct recursion, but it would be best to use the worker pattern:

```
atmostonce = go 0
    where
        go 2 _      _ = False
        go n []     _ = n <= 1
        go n (x:xs) y =
            if x == y
                then go (n + 1) xs y
                else go n xs y
```

The `n <= 1` clause could be replaced by `True`, but ideally it'll short-circuit once `n == 2`, and `n` shouldn't ever be anything other than 0, 1, or 2.  However, for your implementation I believe you are looking for the `elem` function:

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool

atmostonce [] y = True
atmostonce (x:ls) y
    | (x == y) && (y `elem` ls) = False
    | otherwise = True
```

But this won't return you the value you want, since `atmostonce [1, 2, 2, 2] 2` would return `True`.  Instead, you'd need to do recursion down the rest of the list if `x /= y`:

```
atmostonce (x:ls) y
    | (x == y) && (y `elem` ls) = False
    | otherwise = atmostonce ls y
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are good, but you can use `dropWhile` to do the part that's currently done via manual recursion:

```
atMostOnce xs y =
    let afterFirstY = drop 1 $ dropWhile (/= y) xs
    in y `notElem` afterFirstY
```

Comment: That i good as well but i think i will stick to the more basic variant for now, because i am just starting to learn Haskell

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Indeed, the answers are more or less in implementation of `dropWhile (/= y)` with in the base-case (after we found an element), the `elem` hardcoded.

Comment: filter is a good one too `let atMostOnce xs x = (<= 1) . length $ filter (== x) xs`

Comment: @CharlesDurham But that needs to traverse the entire list, since even Haskell isn't lazy enough to evaluate `length` only as far as needed for the comparison to fail. The dropWhile/notElem version on the other hand aborts early once it finds the second y.

Comment: @SebastianRedl good catch! Though I still like filter :) `let atMostOnce xs x = null . drop 1 $ filter (== x) xs`